# Inheritance within generated LINQ classes?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a data warehouse system that relies on LINQ to SQL for its database abstraction.

To cut a long story short, I have a 2011 database which contains many records for this year, I also have a database for each of 2009 and 2010.

These are all located on different servers, but it does not seem to be a problem to have classes within my dbml from different servers.

The problem I have, is that there is table overlap between the two, for example, there is for example a list of customers in both databases. I don't want to have two customer classes in my LINQ to SQL generated code, but would much rather have some sort of inheritance.

I'm struggling to explain the problem maybe, can someone offer any help with how I can have a single class representing multiple tables? I would like to stick to DRY principles.

AK

Comment: Do you mean that the databases have different schemas but contain a subset of tables that are identical?

Comment: I think I get what you are saying. A good example would be if your user information was stored in a User database, but the user's Social Security Number was in the SecurePCI database. You want a user object  with SocialSecurityNumber listed as a property. *note* everything I have been reading on this would rely on custom work with multiple data context objects.

Comment: @Enrico - You are almost correct, although they actually have identical schemas. One is an archive of the 2010 database for example, which only rarely has to be queried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if both database have same table structure, you don't need two classes for both, only the connection string will decide which database the class belongs to.

Comment: So that would mean a different DataContext for each database? I essentially need it to be the case that dependant on the year of database being searched for, a different database is checked.